# What's the transform that relates measures on $[0,1]$ to beta distributions?

Tags: beta-distribution, measure-theory, transform

I'm looking for something that I think is called "[somebody]'s transform", but I can't remember its name.

The idea is that if I have a measure on $[0,1]$ representing the bias of an unknown coin, then I can get the probability of observing $n$ heads and $m$ tails by integrating the measure against a beta distribution. I believe it's also possible to go the other way, so if you know the probability of observing $n$ heads and $m$ tails for every $n,m$, then you can uniquely obtain the measure over $[0,1]$ that they came from.

This is a bit like the discrete Fourier transform in that it relates something function-like to a weighted sum of basis functions. I'm fairly sure it has a name when thought about that way, and I'm looking for that name so that I can read up on its properties.

This seems quite closely related to De Finetti's theorem, but it's really the name of the transform that I'm looking for.

Comment: The logit of a beta distribution is always unimodal. That doesn't sound like what you're looking for. Other way round, a biased coin has to be extraordinarily biased for a transformation (of proportion of heads, or tails, presumably) to be really needed or helpful. Perhaps your real example is quite different.

Comment: Hmm, I might not have explained myself very well. I don't have a specific example in mind, but instead I'm looking for the name of a very general result, which says that *any* probability measure on $[0,1]$ can be represented as a sum of beta distributions in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I have absolutely no idea about that. I recommend editing your question to make that a little more explicit, although "weighted sum of basis functions" is no doubt a sufficient clue for many.

Comment: This sounds like it's equivalent to asserting the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) form a basis for a suitably large function space: just apply a linear transform from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,1]$ to translate that statement into linear combinations of Beta densities.  You have to allow some coefficients to be negative, though.

Comment: @whuber thank you, that comment was helpful. It made me realise that I'm probably thinking of [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) and the way they're used in the [Weierstrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem). But that's a theorem about functions rather than measures, so it's possible I've mis-remembered it. (But De Finetti's theorem suggests something like it *is* possible for measures, so I'm still a bit confused.)